# spread() data frame based on ID, and value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've already looked for several examples, but I did not find any that filtered enabled values & their dates.

```
Date <-c('3/13/2017 6:21', '3/20/2017 6:28','3/13/2017 6:22','3/20/2017 6:28',' 3/13/2017 6:23','3/20/2017 6:28','3/13/2017 6:24',' 3/20/2017 6:28', ' 3/24/2017 6:28')
Enabled_value<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
Helper<-c('39RTU1','39RTU1','39RTU2','39RTU2','39RTU2','39RTU3','39RTU3','39RTU4','39RTU4', '39RTU4')
```

to look like:

```
Helper      Date(Enabled Value =0)     Date (Enabled Value =1) 
39RTU1       3/13/2017 6:20            3/20/2017 6:28
39RTU2       3/13/2017 6:21            3/20/2017 6:28
39RTU3       3/13/2017 6:22            3/20/2017 6:28
39RTU4       3/13/2017 6:24            3/20/2017 6:28
39RTU4       3/24/2017 6:28
```

As you can see, I have timestamps for each observation - each row should be an instance (i.e. moving from Enabled_value from 0 to 1, and if the last Enabled_value for the unit = 0, there should be a new line (see 39RTU4 below).

I have already done extensive work reducing this data set (from 500k to 2k rows).

I'm trying to use `tidyr` and `dplyr`, but my `spread` keeps running errors.

```
> sorted_data1<-spread(sorted_data,Enabled_Value,Helper)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1340, 1342)
```

Comment: I think this question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043098/transpose-columns-group-by-time-and-customer-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the rows aren't uniquely identified based on the way you're trying to spread. So first calculate an index by helper and enabled value. (Note I changed your example data a bit because one of them was of length 10, while the other two were of length 9).

Hopefully this helps. Please feel free to clarify further if this is not what you want.

```
Date <-c('3/13/2017 6:21', '3/20/2017 6:28','3/13/2017 6:22','3/20/2017 6:28',' 3/13/2017 6:23','3/20/2017 6:28','3/13/2017 6:24',' 3/20/2017 6:28', ' 3/24/2017 6:28')
Enabled_value<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
Helper<-c('39RTU1','39RTU1','39RTU2','39RTU2','39RTU2','39RTU3','39RTU3','39RTU4','39RTU4')

df <- tibble(Date, Enabled_value, Helper)
df %>% 
  group_by(Helper, Enabled_value) %>% 
  mutate(count = 1:n()) %>% 
  spread(Enabled_value, Date) %>% 
  rename(Enabled_value_0 = `0`,
         Enabled_value_1 = `1`)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Helper [4]
  Helper count Enabled_value_0 Enabled_value_1
*  <chr> <int>           <chr>           <chr>
1 39RTU1     1  3/13/2017 6:21  3/20/2017 6:28
2 39RTU2     1  3/13/2017 6:22  3/20/2017 6:28
3 39RTU2     2  3/13/2017 6:23            <NA>
4 39RTU3     1  3/13/2017 6:24  3/20/2017 6:28
5 39RTU4     1  3/24/2017 6:28  3/20/2017 6:28
```

Comment: if you add `mutate_at(Enabled_value,as.character)` at the beginning of your pipe chain you save one line, some clarity and manual renaming

Comment: The column names will transfer even without that. I just did the manual renaming at the end to get them to match better (otherwise the column names would be `0` and `1`). I could have also added a line within the mutate I already have to paste "Enabled_value_" to each digit before the spread. I actually felt like the manual renaming was more clear in this case but certainly either works.